# Execute ls star with Runtime.getRuntime() on Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, runtime.exec

I wanto to execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec(); on Java to list files on some directory.

So I wanto to pass this command "ls /mnt/drbd7/i* | tail -1", but because the star the command returns null. And I realy need this star. I need to select the last file modified on the directory. I tryed to use java.io.File but it cannot get the last file.

Does anybody have a hint?
Thanks in advance!
Felipe

Comment: Some code to show how you are using `.exec()` would help. The comments on this question should help

Comment: In a way this is a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13046789/422353) but that one was solved in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `ls /mnt/drbd7/i* | tail -1` won't display the last modified file, since the command `ls` sorts the results by name, by default.
You can do `ls -t /mnt/drbd7/i* | head -1` instead.

You could use the answer to this question:

[How do I find the last modified file in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064694/how-do-i-find-the-last-modified-file-in-a-directory-in-java)

Comment: Maybe in this case the files are being created sequentially and `ls` default behaviour is enough, but good point.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed in a wrong way. I would say that my files have a number on its name, and it represents the date. new Date().getTime(). So if I order them I should get the last one always. Thanks for your advice anyway :)

Comment: You are welcome. But you should not accept this answer then, since it does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the command through the `bash` shell to that it can do a `glob` to convert the wildcards to a file list:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "/bin/bash", "-c", "ls", "/mnt/drbd7/i*", "|", "tail", "-1"});
```

Comment: A minor question. Does it make any difference to use the command as a single `String` or a `String` array?

Comment: Our answers begin to diverge only at the 7th word :)

Comment: @madth3 Doesnt make any difference here, I prefer to use a String array. `ProcessBuilder` is neater too...

Comment: Thanks, I did like this: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "ls /mnt/drbd7/i* | tail -1"});

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the command to a shell which will expand the star—and interpret the pipe symbol. You are starting not one, but two processes.

```
bash -c ls /mnt/drbd7/i* | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Unix, patterns like `*` and `?` in command line parameters are expanded by the command shells and not by the individual programs. There are some exceptions of programs that know how to handle wildcards, but `ls` is not one of them. The same goes for pipes: shells know how to handle them, `java.lang.Runtime` doesn't.

So, if you want to use these features, you would have to do something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c 'ls /mnt/drbd7/i* | tail -1'")
```

But note, that this is a very system-specific solution (it even depends on the current user's configuration) to a problem that can be solved with the means of pure Java (see `java.io.File.listFiles`, `java.nio.file.DirectoryStream`, etc).