# Default character encoding for java console output

Tags: java, windows, utf-8, character-encoding, console

How does Java determine the encoding used for `System.out`?

Given the following class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String s = "xxäñxx";
        System.out.println(s);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("test.txt"), "UTF-8");
        out.println(s);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

It is saved as UTF-8 and compiled with `javac -encoding UTF-8 Foo.java` on a Windows system.

Afterwards on a git-bash console (using UTF-8 charset) I do:

```
$ java Foo
xxõ±xx
$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Foo
xx├ñ├▒xx
$ cat test.txt
xxäñxx
$ java Foo | cat
xxäñxx
$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Foo | cat
xxäñxx
```

What is going on here?

Obviously java checks if it is connected to a terminal and is changing its encoding in that case. Is there a way to force Java to simply output plain UTF-8?

---

I tried the same with the cmd console, too. Redirecting STDOUT does not seem to make any difference there. Without the file.encoding parameter it outputs ansi encoding with the parameter it outputs utf8 encoding.

Comment: `System.out` encodes bytes using the [default encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset--). Sometimes this is even the encoding used by the console.

Comment: But why does `java Foo` output something different that `java Foo|cat`? - The default encoding should be the same.

Comment: did you ensure that you actually _saved_ the file using utf-8 encoding?  it's generally a bad idea to depend on source file encodings.  to be truly safe, define the string using `"\u"` escapes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming that your console still runs under cmd.exe. I doubt your console is really expecting UTF-8 - I expect it is really an OEM DOS encoding (e.g. [850 or 437](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(VS.85).aspx).)

Java will encode bytes using the [default encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset--) set during JVM initialization.

Reproducing on my PC:

```
java Foo
```

Java encodes as windows-1252; console decodes as IBM850. Result: **Mojibake**

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Foo
```

Java encodes as UTF-8; console decodes as IBM850. Result: **Mojibake**

```
cat test.txt
```

cat decodes file as UTF-8; cat encodes as IBM850; console decodes as IBM850.

```
java Foo | cat
```

Java encodes as windows-1252; cat decodes as windows-1252; cat encodes as IBM850; console decodes as IBM850

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Foo | cat
```

Java encodes as UTF-8; cat decodes as UTF-8; cat encodes as IBM850; console decodes as IBM850

This implementation of *cat* must use heuristics to determine if the character data is UTF-8 or not, then transcodes the data from either UTF-8 or ANSI (e.g. windows-1252) to the console encoding (e.g. IBM850.)

This can be confirmed with the following commands:

```
$ java HexDump utf8.txt
78 78 c3 a4 c3 b1 78 78

$ cat utf8.txt
xxäñxx

$ java HexDump ansi.txt
78 78 e4 f1 78 78

$ cat ansi.txt
xxäñxx
```

The *cat* command can make this determination because `e4 f1` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

You can correct the Java output by:

- [Setting the console encoding](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_1252) to the system ANSI value
- Using the [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) type
- Using some [shiv layer](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/go-unicode-on-windows-command-prompt.html#gou_java) as you are doing with *cat*

*HexDump* is a trivial Java application:

```
import java.io.*;
class HexDump {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0])) {
      int r;
      while((r = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.format("%02x ", 0xFF & r);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was sure `cat` simply copies bytes as they are. Obviously it indeed tries to "fix" encoding when writing to a terminal. I was also not aware that git-bash indeed uses the IBM850 cmd terminal. This answer was really helpful.