# Git: Diff does not handles character encoding other than UTF-8?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, encoding, utf-8

Created a repo, added UTF8 and Latin2 encoded files with this content:

```
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP
```

See on https://github.com/bimlas/git-test/commit/872370caf91f1faaf931c1228c797f3d10d6435d

The output of `git log -p 82904e60` is:

```
commit 82904e60d1940c036c8190e2a41de6b423727a7c
Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 27 14:38:35 2015 +0200

    initial commit

diff --git a/fileencoding/latin2.txt b/fileencoding/latin2.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..7165bc9
--- /dev/null
+++ b/fileencoding/latin2.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+<E1>rv<ED>zt<FB>r<F5> t<FC>k<F6>rf<FA>r<F3>g<E9>p^M
+<C1>RV<CD>ZT<DB>R<D5> T<DC>K<D6>RF<DA>R<D3>G<C9>P^M
diff --git a/fileencoding/utf8.txt b/fileencoding/utf8.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..80e1878
--- /dev/null
+++ b/fileencoding/utf8.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép^M
+ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP^M
```

I've git the same output on Linux and Windows (where my locale is Latin2). Tried without pager (`git --no-pager log -p 82904e60`), got the same results without escape codes:

```
commit 82904e6
Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
Date:   2015-07-27 14:38:35 +0200

    initial commit

diff --git a/fileencoding/latin2.txt b/fileencoding/latin2.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..7165bc9
--- /dev/null
+++ b/fileencoding/latin2.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+�rv�zt�r� t�k�rf�r�g�p
+�RV�ZT�R� T�K�RF�R�G�P
diff --git a/fileencoding/utf8.txt b/fileencoding/utf8.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..80e1878
--- /dev/null
+++ b/fileencoding/utf8.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
+ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP
```

The log of the *latin2.txt* is the same, so the problem is not caused by mix of differently encoded files in one output.

How can I set up Git to print the characters as they should appear even without pager?

**EDIT**

I think the problem is not related to the terminal, for example  on Windows PowerShell the *latin2.txt* is fine, but *utf8.txt* is weird:

[image: Same encoding with different output]

Comment: This would require git to a) recognise encodings (which is impossible without having meta data somewhere about which file is encoded how, which I'm sure you didn't add anywhere) and b) convert encodings to your display encoding, which is a task I'm not sure git should get involved in.

Answer (score 4):

Git does not really care about character encodings at all. A file is just a bunch of bytes.

Displaying is done by your terminal. If it is configured to decode as UTF-8 your latin-2 file seems broken. If it is configured to decode as latin-2 you UTF-8 file seems broken.

Maybe the `encoding` attribute (see `git help gitattributes`) is able to give some tools a hint how to decode a file correctly, but I never used this.
For example github might be smart enough to look at this attribute and decode those files differently.

Comment: I think it's not related to terminal: see the end of the question. The `gitattributes` is a bit hacky in my opinion: setting up every file manually is hotbed of issues.

Comment: @Bimba It *is* your terminal! As michas says: if your terminal is expecting latin2, then UTF-8 data appears broken and vice versa. Different terminals give you different results, no big surprise here. Git only outputs the raw binary data, period. It doesn't do anything with encodings.

Comment: @deceze: See the image - same file on same terminal with different output?

Comment: On windows `cat` has some hidden magic converting encodings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24841904/1870481

Comment: @michas Windows doesn't use any *magic* - if a text file starts with a BOM it's assumed to be Unicode otherwise the System locale's settings are used. In fact, in later versions the "System locale" label has been replaced by "Code page used by non-Unicode programs". Some programs (eg Notepad) do attempt to guess whether a file is Unicode even without the BOM, eg by checking whether the first few characters start with NUL, which won't appear in a regular text file unless it uses a Unicode encoding (UTF-8, -16)