# How to decode emoji (unicode) in HBase using Java API?

Tags: java, database, unicode, encoding, hbase

In my HBase table, there are some encoded emoji, like \xF0\x9F\x8C\x8F and \xE2\x9A\xBE. I am trying to use Bytes.toString() to decode them. However, this method use utf-8 which can only decode three bytes code like \xE2\x9A\xBE and the four bytes code like \xF0\x9F\x8C\x8F appears to be a question mark (see below). So how can I decode the four bytes code to emoji and print them out? Anybody has an idea? Thanks in advance!

Example:

The result should be:[image]

But I got [image]

I am so sorry that I forgot to mention that I am using servlet to query HBase and write the content to response.

Comment: are you certain that the encoding is UTF-8? if so, then your conversion is correct, but your OS might not know how to represent the char behind your emoji

Comment: `new String(theBytes, theCharset)`?

Comment: Are you asking the method that I use - Bytes.toString() ? The official documentation shows that this method use utf-8 as default encoding and there is no way to change its encoding.... And I can look into the hbase and found that the emojis are stored in an unicode encoding like  \xF0\x9F\x8C\x8F.

Answer (score 1):

When I read a file that contains the following character ""(F09F8C8F or U+1F30F) and it has a BOM which indicates UTF-8 encoding and I correctly convert it to UTF-8 by using

```
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(selectedFile.toPath());
String fileContents = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

the resulting String is correctly converted and correctly displayed in my Java Swing application. But if I print the same String to the console I get a boxed question mark instead of the symbol. So the character is correctly converted, but it's just your output that gets it messed up.

To recreate this, you can use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  byte[] encoded = { (byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x9F, (byte) 0x8C, (byte) 0x8F };
  String convertedstring = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

  System.out.println("convertedstring: " + convertedstring);

  JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
  dialog.setSize(300, 100);
  dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  dialog.setTitle("encoding-test");
  dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  JLabel label = new JLabel("convertedstring: " + convertedstring);
  dialog.add(label);

  dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Console Output

[image]

JDialog Output

[image]

you might also wanna see [Default character encoding for java console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803733/default-character-encoding-for-java-console-output) and [Java, UTF-8, and Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952/java-utf-8-and-windows-console)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am so sorry that I forgot to mention that I am using servlet to query HBase and write the content to response.

Comment: @DiLuo can you see the emoji in my response? If not than you might wanna update your browser. Also check which HTML content type your response has

Comment: I cannot see the emoji with your code but I set the content type and the encoding of the header to be UTF-16 and now I can see the emoji in the response. Thank you for your inspiration!