# Execute windows command in Java

Tags: java, windows, powershell, runtime.exec

Need to run **netstat -n | find ":3389" | find "ESTABLISHED"** command using Java Runtime.

Tried like: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` but we can't do this if we have **| (pipe)** in our command.

I had found for linux command we can costruct like: 
`String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "grep -c 'Report Process started' /path/to/server.log"}; 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`
but I need for windows, please let me know how we can do?

Comment: same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java despite I would prefer user1121883's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run only `netstat -n` and do the rest in java. You could also write a script, and execute the script instead of separate commands. If you really need to do everything in a single line that has pipes the command must be prefixed with `cmd /C`

Comment: Ya that works, but checking is there any other way similar to linux. Because that way its looking much cleaner and we can find easily what we are doing.

Comment: @KishoreReddy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046789/java-runtime-getruntime-execcmd-not-supporting-pipes

Answer (score 0):

In Windows we can achieve this like:

```
String[] cmd = { "cmd.exe", "/c",
                    "netstat -n | find \":3389\" | find \"ESTABLISHED\"" };
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
```